# How to solve no module found Numpy error?

Tags: python, numpy, anaconda

I'm getting this error message when loading Keras `Original error was: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'`. I'm seen a number of other posts on here trying to solve this issue, but what has worked for them in the past is not working for me.

I've uninstalled and reinstalled Python, Anaconda, and Numpy but still nothing.

Numpy is version 1.16.2

Anaconda3 is versin 3.7.3 64 bit

Does anyone have suggestions how to get around this? My computer did a system update yesterday and since then many things have been broken. I thought doing fresh installs of Anaconda would solve this but it hasn't

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a [bug](https://github.com/alpacahq/pylivetrader/issues/73) on numpy version 1.16, as a work around, you can install `numpy` `1.15`.

```
pip uninstall numpy
pip install 'numpy=1.15'
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion, it now causes :

`
ImportError:
Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed.  Most
likely you are trying to import a failed build of numpy.
If you're working with a numpy git repo, try `git clean -xdf`
(removes all
files not under version control).  Otherwise reinstall numpy.

Original error was: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
`

And I noticed by pip had numpy 1.16.1 installed, where as anaconda had 1.16.2 installed. I deleted them both and install 1.15 on each

Comment: It may be due to missing dll's your system and that's something I cannot help.